# Definition of a universal example

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, definition

I'm not sure how the term is being used here:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ indeterminates over $R$. Set $P = R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$.

Given a ring homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow R'$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in R'$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\pi: P \rightarrow R'$ with $\pi\restriction_R = \phi$ and $\pi(X_i) = x_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. 
Another way to state this is that $P$ is a universal example of an $R$-algebra with $n$ distinguished elements.

How is it used in general? Also, this example was used as an example of a "universal mapping property" and could you help clarify what this means?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property . Universal properties and universal objects are not so easy a thing to describe in words; I think the path to understanding them lies in becoming familiar with enough examples until you've absorbed the underlying idea. Very roughly speaking, they are a strong and surprisingly useful generalization of the idea of a minimal element. Slightly less roughly speaking, at least in some contexts it's reasonable to think of a universal object as the laziest way to accomplish something.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "minimal element"? I prefer to think of it as "minimal description" or perhaps "definition that gives you the thing with minimal amount of effort". I think Wikipedia calls it "most efficient construction". But minimal element sounds as if we're talking about a poset. Are we?

Comment: @Matt: in some sense, yes. Every universal object is an initial or terminal object in a suitable category.

Comment: @modnar [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130850/free-group-and-universal-property) is a thread about the free group, one of the easiest examples of a universal property and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132438/universal-properties-again)'s a follow up, still about the free group. There is also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130950/free-groups-unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132540/universal-properties-and-diagrams). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think "universal example" here is an abuse of language to mean "example of a universal property".

As pointed out by t.b. in the comments:

By definition, an $R$-algebra for a commutative ring $R$ is a pair $(S, f)$ where $f: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism and $S$ is a commutative ring.

An $R$-algebra $A$ with $n$ distinguished elements is hence a triplet $((a_1, \dots, a_n), A, f)$ for some $a_i \in A$ where $f: R \to A$ is a ring homomorphism. An $R$-algebra homomorphism between two $R$-algebras with $n$ distinguished elements $((a_1, \dots, a_n), A, f)$ , $((b_1, \dots, b_n), B, f^\prime)$ is an $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi : A \to B$ such that $\varphi (a_i) = b_i$.

Then the universal property that's stated is:

An $R$-algebra with $n$ distinguished elements is a triplet $((X_1, \dots, X_n), P, \varphi)$ satisfying the following universal property: for every $R$-algebra $((r_1^\prime, \dots, r_n^\prime), R^\prime, \phi)$ with $n$ distinguished elements $r_1^\prime, \dots, r_n^\prime \in R^\prime$ there exists a unique $R$-algebra homomorphism $\pi: P \to R^\prime$ such that $\pi\restriction_R = \pi \circ  \varphi = \phi$ and $\pi (X_i) = r_i^\prime$ for the $n$ distinguished elements $r_i^\prime \in R^\prime$ and $n$ distinguished elements in $P$. Can't resist to add the corresponding diagram:

[image]

In general, many universal mapping properties read as follows:

The *thingamajig* is an object $B$ and a morphism $m: A \to B$ such that for every object $C$ and morphism $n: A \to C$ there is a unique morphism $\varphi : B \to C$ such that the diagram of morphisms commutes, that is, such that $\varphi \circ m = n$.

Comment: Your second paragraph is a bit confusingly phrased: I'd define first what an $R$-algebra with $n$ distinguished elements is, then observe that the $R$-algebra $P = R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ *has* $n$ distinguished elements $X_1,\dots,X_n$; and only *then* state the the universal property of the polynomial algebra.

Comment: @t.b. Better? ${}$

Comment: My understanding is that an $R$-algebra with $n$ distinguished elements is an $R$-algebra $A$ *together* with an $n$-tuple of elements $a_1,\dots,a_n \in A$. If $(A,a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $(B,b_1,\dots,b_n)$ are two algebras, a morphism is an $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi\colon A \to B$ such that $\varphi(a_i) = b_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$. Your ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R \to R'$ turns $R'$ into an $R$-algebra and it extends uniquely to $\pi:R[X_1,\dots,X_n] \to R'$ such that $\pi X_i = r_i$ witnessing the universal property of $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ with distinguished elements $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

Comment: @t.b. I edited it. Is it better now? I really just repeated half of your comment. Do the distinguished elements really have to be ordered?

Comment: Well, if they're not ordered then the universal example is the subalgebra of symmetric polynomials (and the inclusion corepresents the "forget about the ordering" functor).  So, it depends what you care about.

Comment: What Aaron said (in other words: yes, they really have to be ordered). The first sentence of what is now the fourth paragraph is still confusing the polynomial algebra $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and its universal property. Try to write this more carefully. Maybe you should also state explicitly that a (commutative) ring $R'$ with a homomorphism $\phi: R \to R'$ is the same thing a commutative $R$-algebra.

Comment: @t.b. I fixed it now I think. Better? : )

Comment: No... :( Your edit made it worse... What is $S$? What do you assume $A$ to be? Why should one think of a ring with distinguished elements as a polynomial ring? How is $\mathbb{Z}$ with $3,4,7$ as distinguished elements a polynomial ring (= commutative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra) over $\mathbb{Z}$? What is $X_i$ in the universal property of $(P,\varphi)$?

Comment: :,( .... ${}{}{}$

Comment: @t.b. I don't know what I assume $A$ to be, other than an $R$-algebra : ( As for the polynomial ring example: it seemed like the standard example of an $R$ algebra. That's what I thought, anyway. Now I'm confused : ( And as I'd already written, $X_i$ are some elements in $P$, I don't know what you mean by what they are.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the confusion is of a mathematical nature, or not, but what I'm sure of is that your presentation is really clumsy: You write: "An $R$-algebra $A$ with $n$ distinguished elements is a pair $(a_1,\dots,a_n,A)$ for some $a_i \in A$". First of all, I see an $(n+1)$-tuple... Then two paragraphs later, an $R$-algebra with distinguished elements is a pair $(P,\varphi)$ having a certain universal property? Then: do you really *write* that the $X_i$ are supposed to be the distinguished elements of $P$?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I don't know how this happened. I will fix it but not right now. (A bit busy, have something important coming up)

Comment: @t.b. I'm sorry but re-reading your comment reveals that it's not right what you say: You say you see an $n+1$ tuple. But I did not write $(a_1, \dots , a_n, A)$, I wrote $((a_1, \dots, a_n), A)$. In any case, there are typos/mistakes in my post which I will have to fix.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry about that, I must have been hallucinating because of tiredness; also, the comment came out way harsher than I intended... Not my day yesterday. I suggest to change the beginning of the last paragraph before the diagram into "A *universal* $R$-algebra with $n$ distinguished elements ..." because otherwise it seems as if you had two conflicting definitions of $R$-algebras with $n$ distinguished elements.

Comment: @t.b. It's ok, I can tell when you're having a bad day. As for the algebras: is not one of them the definition in terms of universal property and one in terms of "construction"? Although there is not much to be constructed in this case.

Comment: OK, thanks :) Only the *polynomial algebra* has the universal property you describe: If you distinguish the elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ in an *arbitrary* $R$-algebra $A$ you can extend the ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R \to A$ defining the algebra structure on $A$ to an algebra homomorphism $\varphi\colon R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ (basically evaluation; interpreting $X_i$ as $a_i$: e.g. $r X_{1}^7 X_{5}^3 \mapsto r a_{1}^7 a_{5}^3$). The $X_i$ are "free variables" in P: no relations beyond commutation, while the $a_i$ might have relations in $A$, you can't send them arbitrarily into another ring.

Comment: @t.b. Let me see whether I understand what you wrote there: when you write *polynomial algebra* you mean a ring with $n$ additional elements (not in $R$) with a ring acting on all of it. When you write *arbitrary $R$-algebra* you mean one with $n$ elements in the algebra that are distinguished (and a ring acting on it). ?  (should be writing like mad but so tired that I'm going to watch Dr. Who now. See you later maybe.)

Comment: Have fun! I mean *the* [polynomial ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) $R[X_1,\dots,X_n] = P$ in $n$ indeterminates over $R$. As a ring extension of $R$ this $P$ has a natural $R$-algebra structure (inclusion of constants) and it has the distinguished elements $X_1,\dots,X_n$. We set up the category of $R$-algebras with $n$ distinguished elements and inside this category $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ has the universal property. Yes, I mean what you'd write $((a_1,\dots,a_n),A,\phi)$ by *arbitrary $R$-algebra* [after we picked(=distinguished) our $a_i$'s]; we extend $\phi$ from $R$ to $P$.